# Read string portions based on format

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a parser to read values from a string based on a pattern. For example:

I need to write a method so it accepts `"12:04:03"` and a pattern example such as `"{hh}:{mm}:{ss}"` and it can parse it to `return` the corresponding portions `("12,"04","03"`).

I'm not trying to actually parse time, it's just a practical example. The pattern groups can be hardcoded.

**What I think I could do:**

Parse the string with `RegEx` and then find the original content looping through the `string`.

While this would work, I think there might be a more efficient way or even pre-built solution in the `Framework`.

So, how can I solve this problem elegant and efficiently?

Comment: Isn't this what regex does? `(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)` would match your example, and then you can pull the values out of the groups.

Comment: If every group has the same match rules, you can simply do `Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()`. You can add a `.Select(x => int.Parse)` before `ToArray` if you assume all values will actually be parsable into int without any special handling.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The thing is that the original string could be completely different and I need the user of the function to tell the method WHERE is the info. Consider this string instead: "It's 12PM with 04 hours and 03 minutes." The pattern would be "It's {hh}PM with {hh} hours and {mm} minutes."

Comment: So.. `It's (\d\d)PM with (\d\d) hours and (\d\d) minutes`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The thing is I have no way of knowing which values are which without relying on the order. The order in my case is not guaranteed. That's why I want to use predefined placeholders like {hh}, {mm}, {ss}

Comment: @Blorgbeard That way I can parse 556012 as "{ss}{mm}{hh}". Also remember that my problem isn't about time, so DateTime class related solutions will not solve my problem.

Comment: You know you can name your capture groups: `(?<yo>\d\d)` will match 2 digits and you can access the group by `match.Groups["yo"]`

Comment: You can use named groups in regex: `(?<ss>\d\d)(?<mm>\d\d)(?<hh>\d\d)`. Admittedly the syntax is more verbose, but you could convert from yours to a suitable regex, then just run the regex and extract group values by name.

Comment: I didn't know I could name regex groups. I can indeed work with that. I'll look into it when I get home. I should also learn regex properly once and for all... Thank you YoryeNathan and Blorgbeard You are both very kind.

Comment: Can you please clarify if your goal to write some sort of equivalent of regex OR come up approach to parse your strings? Answers would be quite different (and RegEx approach is already well covered in comments...)